# TypeScript - how to exclude one of the typings?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm creating a web + mobile app using react-native and TypeScript. So essentialy, I have two different outputs for two different TS configs.

For the web, my target is `es5` and module `commonjs`. So I have to use the `es6-shim` typing to make `tsc` happy when transpiling.

For mobile (different `tsconfig.json`), my target is `es6` and module `es6`. The problem is that this collides with the `es6-shim` typing and `tsc` outputs many "Duplicate identifier" errors. If I remove the shim, `tsc` is happy (but then web transpilation stops working).

I've tried excluding the typing in the tsconfig for mobile like so:

```
...
"exclude": [
    "typings/globals/es6-shim",
...
```

...but no luck, TypeScript compiler finds the typing anyway (probably because of a reference from `typings/index.d.ts` to the es6-shim typing) and still outputs many "Duplicate identifier" errors for the mobile build.

Am I doing the ignore the wrong way? Am I thinking about it wrong and there is some other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude `typings/index.d.ts` for the ES6 build as well.

If you have something else in that file that needs to be included in the ES6 build, then move out `es6-shim` reference into a separate `.d.ts` file for the ES6 build and exclude that instead.

Comment: Thank you! Excluding the `typings/index.d.ts` file looks to be the correct solution. TSC manages to find all the typing definition files automatically even without the index file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different `tsconfig.json` files, you could have two typings folders, both with the appropriate files for mobile/web respectively. This would depend slightly on the structure of your project, if there was a separated directory where it would make sense to keep these.

However, I would probably be inclined to just ignore your `index.d.ts` file also and explicitly include your declaration files, for each build type. e.g.

mobile tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
    },
    "files": [
        "core.ts",
        "typings/globals/something_else.d.ts"
        // Your other files to be compiled or declarations (everything bar your es6-shim)
    ]
}
```

and then you could do the same for web, including your es6-shim, or just add everything i.e. the`index.d.ts`

Comment: Does the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md) tool support having multiple configs with separate directories? I'm not sure. The suggestion would work with TypeScript, but adding and managing new typings with the typings tool would be a hassle if it doesn't support this.

Comment: @RonaldZarīts You mentioned in the question you have two tsconfig files?

Comment: I'm not the poster. I think it's implied that the poster has two tsconfig.json files, but I'm referring to `typings.json` file for the `typings` tool - it is a separate tool with a separate config file.

Comment: @RonaldZarīts Ahh I see - sorry. I don't think that matters, you would want typings to install all declarations and then for one tsc compilation option to use all but one of them and for the other to use all of them. So only one typings configuration.

Comment: No worries. You suggested having two separate `/typings` folders, e.g. `/typings-es5` and `/typings-es6`. While it would work with `tsc` compiler, I'm just saying it would be a hassle to manage the typing packages later. It looks like `typings` tool only works with a file called `typings.json` and writes everything to a folder called `/typings`. Having a different folder would break the tool, and that would be a hassle, since the .d.ts typing packages get updated periodically.

Comment: @RonaldZarīts I went on to suggest a better approach, but I was thinking if the OP has a web and a mobile directory in his project root, then there could be `web/typings` and a `mobile/typings` file.

Comment: I've got just one typings folder. My goal is to share as much code between mobile and web as possible (which is easy with React and React Native). I'd like to continue managing the typing definitions using the `typings` tool. I'm not sure if explicitly adding the typing definitions is a good solution, as the `typings.native.json` config for mobile could easily get out of sync if I forget to add the typing definition after downloading it using the `typings` tool.

Comment: @freddy Well, it would be quite obvious as the compiler will start failing with fairly easy to diagnose errors. The TypeScript definitions story is fairly hands-on at the moment anyway, so I personally see this approach as not too bad,as you keep your single definitions directory and use typings tools and ahre as much code as you like. I am not sure if it would work, but you could try and add the filesGlob property and define everything except `es6-shim` in the typings directory - which would solve your concern?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards It would be a pain to explicitly add every typing definition file. On the other hand, globbing the files and excluding the `es6-shim`, as you are suggesting, could be a not-too-bad solution :) @Ronald's solution is, however, much simpler and works :)